# fetched data from firestore as initial value of useState it gives me udefined value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set the fetched data from firestore as initial value of useState but it gives me undefined value because I want to update user profile and I don't know the user edits or updates which property because I want to keep the other properties of the user the same, only change the edited one.

I've tried this code, but it gives me this error:
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field surname in document users/DQjpLaKYVgVuH9TeqNomIEyuMJB2)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { doc, onSnapshot, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from '../../firebase';


export default function Form({ setEditForm }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [currentUser] = useAuthState(auth);
  
  // fetching user information from firestore
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const docRef = await doc(db, 'users', currentUser.uid)
      try {
        await onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
          setUser({
            ...doc.data(), id: doc.id
          })
        })

      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }

    }
    getUser()
  }, [])

  const [name, setName] = useState(user.firstName);
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState(user.surname);
    const [biography, setBiography] = useState(user.biography);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(user.location);

  // updating user's profile
  const updateProfile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const docRef = doc(db, 'users', currentUser.uid);
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      firstName: name,
      surname: surname,
      biography: biography,
      location: location
    })
  }

  console.log(user)
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={updateProfile}
      className="flex flex-col w-4/6 lg:w-3/6"
    >
      <div className="lg:flex lg:flex-row lg:justify-between lg:gap-6">
        <div className="lg:flex lg:flex-col lg:w-1/2">
          <h2 className="text-left text-[#4699C2] font-bold py-2">Name: </h2>
          <div className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={name}
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              className="w-full py-2 px-4 opacity-50 focus:opacity-100"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="lg:flex lg:flex-col lg:w-1/2">
          <h2 className="text-left text-[#4699C2] font-bold py-2">Surname: </h2>
          <div className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={surname}
              value={surname}
              onChange={(e) => setSurname(e.target.value)}
              className="opacity-50 px-4 focus:opacity-100 w-full py-2"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h2 className="text-left text-[#4699C2] font-bold py-2">Biograhpy: </h2>
      <div className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md">
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setBiography(e.target.value)}
          className="opacity-50 px-4 focus:opacity-100 w-full py-4"
        >
          {biography}
        </textarea>
      </div>

      <h2 className="text-left text-[#4699C2] font-bold py-2">Location: </h2>
      <div className="border border-gray-300 rounded-md">
        <input
          placeholder={location}
          value={location}
          onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
          className="opacity-50 px-4 focus:opacity-100 w-full py-2"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center py-4">
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="SAVE"
          className="bg-[#4699C2] text-white fong-bold w-24 py-3 rounded-full mx-4 font-bold hover:bg-[#026FC2] hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-[#026FC2] focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-[#026FC2] active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
        />
        <input
          onClick={() => {
            setEditForm(false);
          }}
          type="reset"
          value="CANCEL"
          className="bg-[#4699C2] cursor-pointer lg:bg-white hover:bg-[#026FC2] hover:text-white hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-[#026FC2] focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:text-white active:bg-[#026FC2] active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out text-white lg:text-[#4699C2] lg:border lg:border-[#4699C2] fong-bold w-24 py-3 rounded-full font-bold"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code looks good to me. check the initial value of the surname that is fetched from firebase. maybe because of some typo user.surname gets undefined.

Comment: No actually there is no typo but the problem with fetching when I console.log of the states like name biography... it gives me undefined value I want to put the fetched data to as initial value because I want to give permisson user to update their profile but maybe they will update just surname so I want the other properties to keep the same not null if I set null to initial value so when the user update their surname the other properties will be null

Comment: instead of storing the response in one single state, first declare all the states like name, biography, surname, etc... to null. then in useState set all the states ex. setName(doc.data().Name). sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: wow it worked thank you so much it's been two days I'm dealing with this error I really appreciate your help

Comment: Seems like your problem is solved, Can you share your solution as answer so that it will help others?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this as community wiki, As suggested by @yograjtandel, instead of storing the response in one single state, first declare all the states like name, biography, surname, etc... to null. then in `useState` set all the states ex. `setName(doc.data().Name)`.